# PgConnection.getNotifications() is empty when using Hikari

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I need to implement LISTEN/NOTIFY PostgreSQL in spring app.
I am using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.5.8. When I Autowired DataSource, by default it is HikariDataSource, to receive notifications, I need PgConnection which I get from Connection from DataSource, all this is wrapped by HikariProxyConnection, but in this case, I always receive an empty notification array.

[code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js4Aw.png)

In case I am getting the connection using DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "pwd") all works if fine a I receive notifications.

Do you have some ideas how it can be solved?

Comment: Can confirm the same issue, it also doesn't matter if you set a timeout millis in `getNotifications`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection is set to `autoCommit = false`, so the `LISTEN` statement is never committed.

To fix this, you need to `.commit()` your LISTEN statement, or change HikariCP to use `autocommit`.

```kotlin
    val pgconnection = hikariDataSource.connection
        .unwrap(PgConnection::class.java)

    val stmt = pgconnection.createStatement()
    stmt.execute("LISTEN mymessage")
    stmt.close()
    pgconnection.commit() // Here's the fix!

    while (true) {
        val notifications = pgconnection.getNotifications(Int.MAX_VALUE)

        println(notifications)
        println("Size: ${notifications.size}")
        for (notification in notifications) {
            println(notification)
        }
    }
}
```

There's even a issue on HikariCP's GitHub, however trying to find this issue was *hard*, because for some reason it doesn't show up on Google. I was only able to find this issue because [Brett created a gist trying to replicate the reported issue](https://gist.github.com/brettwooldridge/e23b7be6b984567521d12a74738e4922) and the class name has the issue ID. https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/828